# Check if "before last" element is 'x' (combining prev() and end() )

Tags: php

I have an array of integers in php and what I'd like to do is check if the *before* the last element is equal to 'x'. I've tried this:

```
if(prev(end($array)) == $x)
```

But it returns an error **Warning: prev() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given** given the fact ***end*** returns the last element instead of a pointer. Any idea on this one?

Comment: once the end is executed, it returns a string (as the error states), so on the evaluation of prev, its not an array anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this index `count($array)-2` could help :

```
if($array[count($array)-2] == $x)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if($array[count($array)-2] == $x)
```

### Update :

This will work also

```
end($array);
if(prev($array) == $x) {}
```

Comment: You need to subtract 2 because arrays are 0-based.

Comment: @TechnoKnol he want " before the last element " so it should be : if($array[count($array)-2] == $x)